# How to refresh page data with Onsen UI + AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I have two pages with two different controllers, Master and Detail.
Master consists of list of data from database, and an add button in toolbar,data is fetched from db in controller initializers ,when user taps on add button it will go to Detail page and enters the data and then click the save and gets back to the Master page.

Now how can I refresh the Master page data, since the page already exists the controller initializer is not called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something called factory in order for data to be persistent and also maybe .run in Angular to get the data on the initial start of the app.

Research a bit on https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services and .run https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module

Comment: Do you mean having a factory for master data and then using $apply to refresh the master list? if yes how can I found the the detail page is poped?

Comment: Since when you go on the detail page you want to save some data to the Master you probably want to have a factory to do that. So when the user comes to the details , presses save, you update the factory which has the master details data, then when the user comes to master page it actually reads the data from the factory.